# How to count the number of rows containing a specific phrase in PowerBi?

Tags: powerbi

I'm using power bi.
I have a columns name "status"
and I want to count the number of rows in this column that contains the string "cnn".
Sometimes the string in the middle of the phrase sometimes in the end.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

[CONTAINSSTRING](https://dax.guide/containsstring/) seems like this key here.

Try something like this:

```
COUNTROWS (
    FILTER ( Table1, CONTAINSSTRING ( Table1[Status], "cnn" ) )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the number itself for a KPI visual, you wrap the count statement that takes a particular column in a calculate and then use the CONTAINSSTRING as a filter for that particular column

```
CountCNN=CALCULATE(COUNT(Table["status"]),CONTAINSSTRING(Table["status"],"cnn"))
```